# Vimgrep do not open the first occurrence found in a new buffer

Tags: vim, vimgrep

I used to do research ag.vim. Currently it opens the file in a buffer of the first occurrence, default behavior vimgrep. I'd like to know if there is an option to not do that and be able to navigate directly to the quicklist after searching.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found via the vim irc room on freenode:

```
:Ag! my_occurence
```

So it does not open any files in a new buffer.

Comment: good find. i've added `cabbrev Ag Ag!` to my vimrc so that `:Ag` always maps to `:Ag!`